# Pycharm auto complete in external python library

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using pycharm 2018.1.2(Community Edition)
I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Before update pycharm to this version, it suggested function or class in external python library.

However after updating pycharm, it doesn't suggest functions or classes in external package.

[image: It recognize python package as single text file]

[image]

I can't find how to solve this problem.
Is this happening because I'm using coummnity version?

[image]

I had already set interpreter for project.
It doesn't suggest class or method in package but when I running source code it works well with out any error.

Comment: Is the script running or PyCharm loses library path? Is "Preferences>Python Interpreter" the one you desire? You may force PyCharm to reindex libraries by switching interpreter version.

Comment: is it just with `numpy`? your `Project Interpreter` is missing `numpy` so its not auto-completing. Try it with `Beatifulsoup` or something else in this screenshot. It **should** work

Comment: No with all packages such as Flask, PyPDF2, tensorflow or other packages. But it suggest methods and classes in BeautifulSoap.

Comment: if its suggesting for Beautifulsoup then its working.

Comment: Then why numpy, Flask, PyPDF2 and other packages doesn't suggest class or method?

Answer (score 0):

`PyCharm` may not have an interpreter configured.
Try adding a local `python` interpreter using:

[image]

[Src](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)

---

You may also try **[Cleaning out the system caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html)**  using `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` and rebooting your workstation.

Comment: I already set project interpreter and I tried cleaning out the system caches. However it still doesn't work

Comment: You may have to re-install it.

Comment: I already re-installed pycharm for more than 5 times but problems aren't solved